# Can a user's AccountKit id for an app ever change?

Tags: facebook, account-kit

I've integrated Facebook's AccountKit as the login system for my app. It has some bugs but usually works fine.

My developer reported a fairly bad experience though recently. He had to restart his computer, thus clearing the sessions, and when he went to re-login to the app via AccountKit, he realized that the same email address he had been using returned a different user_id than the one it had been returning previously. This of course caused a problem in that our backend could not find any account relating to the new Accountkit id.

I've been unable to find much information about this. I'm wondering if this is a bug or a feature! Any further illumination on this subject is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every login will return a different Access Token or Authorization Code as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/accesstokens

If you get the Account ID from the Access Token, it should always be the same for a user entering the same email address. What you're describing sounds like a bug and if you can still reproduce it, you should submit a bug report and someone will look into it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Haven't reproduced it so far. Thinking about writing a test just to make sure. My dev is in eastern Europe, not sure if that makes ANY difference, but it's definitely concerning. The id that he logs in with now is still the same different one that was returned so the old account was completely wiped out. I will let you know if we run some tests and if we file a bug report. Thanks for the clarification!